# Error inside the class

Tags: android, class

I have created this class, but there is an error last part saying 
"Syntax error on token "(", delete this token" on the "**timers.schedule part**"

```
public class refrend
{
   Timer timers = new Timer();
   final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
   int initial = 1000;
   int looper = 6000;
   TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    new activityIns().execute();

                }
            });
        }
   };             
   timers.schedule(task, initial, looper);
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: are you sure there should be a ; after the curly bracket just above timers.schedule(...)?

Comment: Delete the ; before timers.schedule...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is to create a function

```
 public class refrend {

    Timer timers = new Timer();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    int initial = 1000;
    int looper = 6000;
   public void your_Function(){
       TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               handler.post(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {

                       // new activityIns().execute();

                   }
               });
           }
       };
       timers.schedule(task, initial, looper);
   }
}
```

now you can call that function in you class by your_Functino();
and if you want to use that function out side of class create it object and call
it

```
 refrend object=new refrend();
 object.your_Function();
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, sorry i havnt figure that out, cause im cramming now, i have a deadline.. ur help is highly appreciated :)